# Infinite loop with RE2::FindAndConsumeN

Tags: c++, re2

I'm trying to count how many occurrences a pattern has in an expression:

```
while (RE2::FindAndConsumeN(&stringPiece, regex, nullptr, 0))
{
    ++matches;
}
```

Testing it with :

```
auto stringPiece = RE2::StringPiece("aaa");
auto regexp = RE2::re2("a*");
```

Ends up with the loop running forever (I expected it to return 1)
Does anyone know how am I using it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does it loop endlessly or does it stuck in the FACN function?

Comment: @Thomas loop endlessly (matches is always incremented)

Comment: And what's the output if you print `&stringPiece` ?

Comment: It does not advance , as if a* matches an empty string

Comment: What if you change it to `a+` just to test?

Comment: Or change `0` to `1`

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**  The find of findAndConsume fails because it cant find something at the beginning of an input. Failing implies that **the match is found**, but i'm guessing it can't move the buffer right, causing the infinte loop.

---

According to the [header of re2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/re2.h) :

```
  // Like Consume(..), but does not anchor the match at the beginning of the
  // string.  That is, "pattern" need not start its match at the beginning of
  // "input".  For example, "FindAndConsume(s, "(\\w+)", &word)" finds the next
  // word in "s" and stores it in "word".
```

> **That is, "pattern" need not start its match at the beginning of "input"**

In your code, your pattern is being match at the beginning of the input, hence the wrong behaviour.

If you feed findAndConsume something like  :

```
auto stringPiece = RE2::StringPiece("baaa");
```

You should have no more errors in your loop.

Or if you want you can just use ConsumeN() instead :

```
  // Like FullMatch() and PartialMatch(), except that pattern has to
  // match a prefix of "text", and "input" is advanced past the matched
  // text.  Note: "input" is modified iff this routine returns true.
  static bool ConsumeN(StringPiece* input, const RE2& pattern, // 3..16 args
                       const Arg* const args[], int argc);
```

Comment: I'd like to handle cases both where the input start with pattern and both where it does not. I'm interpreting "need not start" as it may or may not start. Am I wrong?

Comment: If `findAndConsume fails` then it wouldn't go in an endless loop

Comment: The input pattern and string are given to me as params. I'd like to count the number of pattern occurrences in the string, I'm not looking to feed to input where it will succeed

Comment: @Thomas fails != return 0 , it meant it had a wrong behaviour. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Shmoopy I'd suggest to give it a try with ConsumeN(); only, and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

RE2::FindAndConsumeN return a bool if the pattern is found, I would not call it on a while loop since your pattern & source doesn't change.

This may help you in the way of calling the function:

```
re2::RE2::Arg match;
re2::RE2::Arg* args[] = { &match };
re2::RE2::FindAndConsumeN(NULL, pattern, args, 1);
```

Comment: Actually, the input does change, hence the 'consume'.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say that "It does not advance, as if `a*` matches an empty string".  That's exactly correct.  `a*` can match the empty string.  It can also find a zero-length match in any other string.

In your example, during the first call to `FindAndConsume()` the regex matches the entire input string.  Because the match is consumed, the input string becomes the empty string when the call returns.  During the second and all following calls to `FindAndConsume()` the regex matches the empty string.

If instead you have the regex `a*` and the input string `bbb` then `FindAndConsume()` will forever return `true` without modifying the input string.  `a*` finds a zero-length match at the start of the string `bbb`.  Consuming this match does not change the input string.  So here too you'd have an infinite loop.

So the conclusion is that you can't safely loop over `FindAndConsume()` if your regular expression may find zero-length matches.  Either ensure your regex cannot find zero-length matches, or add extra logic to the loop to make sure it consumes at least one character with each iteration.